# Closed form of $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + ... + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{x}}}}$

Tags: trigonometry, closed-form, nested-radicals

How to prove the following formula,

$$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + ... + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{x}}}} = 
    \begin{cases} 
          2 \cos\Big[\frac{1}{2^{n}}\Big(\pi + \arctan{\frac{\sqrt{x(4-x)}}{x-2}}\Big)\Big] & 0 < x < 2 \\
          2 \cos\Big[\frac{1}{2^{n}}\arctan{\frac{\sqrt{x(4-x)}}{x-2}}\Big] & 2 < x \leq 4 \\
          2 \cosh\Big[\frac{1}{2^{n}}\text{arctanh}{\frac{\sqrt{x(x-4)}}{x-2}}\Big] & x \geq 4 
       \end{cases}
    \
$$
where $x \in \mathcal{R}$ and $n$ is the number of time the square root symbol $\sqrt{\text{ }\text{ }}$  appears.

This formula is a generalization of the following formula, which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649968/proof-of-an-equality-involving-cosine-sqrt2-sqrt2-cdots-sqrt2-s?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132412/is-there-an-explicit-formula-that-gives-the-value-of-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), and  which can be obtained by taking the above general formula in the limit $x = 2$.

$$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + ... + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}} = 2\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\Big)$$

Comment: Just induct on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $a=2\cos(y)$ then
$$2+a= 2 + 2\cos(y)= 4 \cos^2(\frac{y}{2}) \,.$$

So write $\sqrt{x}=2 \cos(\alpha)$ and use the above formula:

$$2 +\sqrt{x}= (2 \cos(\frac{\alpha}{2}))^2 \\
2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{x}}=2+2\cos(\alpha/2)= (2\cos(\alpha/4))^2 \\
...$$

Comment: How could one find the formula without knowing it first ?

Comment: @Zakhurf The basis for this is the half-angle formula $\cos^2\left(\frac x2\right)=1+\cos x$ which follows from the double-angle formula. This is a more-or-less well-known identity.

Comment: @Zakhurf That's the well known half angle formula.